# Is it possible to let MySQL output in percentile groups?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with messages per user:

```
users
----------------
user_id messages
----------------
  725       0
   30       0
 1436       1
10454       4
    .       .
    .       .
 1507      901
```

The table contains 74,500 users. The table is sorted `ASC` for the numer of messages. I now want to count the number of tweets per percentile, so:

```
SELECT SUM(messages) FROM users LIMIT     0, 745;
SELECT SUM(messages) FROM users LIMIT   745, 745;
SELECT SUM(messages) FROM users LIMIT  1490, 745;
.
.
SELECT SUM(messages) FROM users LIMIT 73755, 745;
```

I can do this, no problem. And I could write a script to fire the queries to the database. But I was wondering, isn't it possible to let MySQL output the total number of messages per usergroup? So the output would be something like

```
group  users         total_messages
-----------------------------------
  1       0 - 745     451
  2     745 - 1490   5627
  .      .      .      .
  .      .      .      .
100   73755 - 74500  2654
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select group_id,concat(MIN(user_id) ,'-',MAX(user_id)) as users,
SUM(messages) as messages  
from
  (SELECT ceil(@rownum:= @rownum+1/745 ) AS group_id,user_id,messages
  FROM users, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  order by user_id)a
  group by group_id
```

if you want group range also to be displayed , you could do this

```
select group_id,concat(MIN(rownum) ,'-',MAX(rownum)) as groups,
concat(MIN(user_id) ,'-',MAX(user_id)) as users,
SUM(messages) as messages
from
  (SELECT ceil(@rownum:= @rownum+1/745 ) AS group_id,@slno:= @slno+1 
  as rownum,user_id,messages
  FROM users, (SELECT @rownum:=0)k,(select @slno:=0) r
  order by user_id)a
  group by group_id
```

Comment: It works, but I don't get the `USERS` output. The first 3 records are `1 3-1271 120978', '2 1273-2616 53841', and `3 2617-4032 22800`. So in the first record are `1268` users, in the second `1343` and in the third `1415`? It was expected to be `745` in all instances. You're working with `ceil()` which (imho) could be a problem. Is it possible to just take bites of 745 intill it has reached max? So that if the table would get an additional 1000 users, 750 would be in the next-to-last group, and 250 in the final group.

Comment: @Pr0no: 3-1271 are the min(userid)-max(userid) in the first 745 records

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT grp + 1                                       AS `group`,
       CONCAT(grp*grpsize, ' - ', (grp+1)*grpsize-1) AS users,
       SUM(messages)                                 AS total_messages
FROM (
  SELECT   @i:=@i+1, @i DIV grpsize AS grp, grpsize, messages
  FROM     users, (SELECT COUNT(*) / 100 AS grpsize, @i:=0 FROM users) t
  ORDER BY messages
) t
GROUP BY grp
```

Comment: Let me have a look at it :-) Thanks for the help; I'll get back to it.